# SolverStudio Install Error on .vsto

Tags: solver, failed-installation

This is the code, i have Windows 7 64x 86x, Office 2010, installed [Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54251) and .NET version 4.0.0.0

This is the error code, i changed the log path to my folder to PATH:

```
PO/SolverStudio_00_09_03_00 20160520/SolverStudio/SolverStudio/SolverStudio.vsto

************** Texto de Exceção **************
System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: Não houve êxito no download de file:///PATH/SolverStudio_00_09_03_00 20160520/SolverStudio/SolverStudio/SolverStudio.vsto. ---> System.Net.WebException: Não foi possível localizar uma parte do caminho 'PATH\SolverStudio_00_09_03_00 20160520\SolverStudio\SolverStudio\SolverStudio.vsto'. ---> System.Net.WebException: Não foi possível localizar uma parte do caminho 'PATH\SolverStudio_00_09_03_00 20160520\SolverStudio\SolverStudio\SolverStudio.vsto'. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Não foi possível localizar uma parte do caminho 'PATH\SolverStudio_00_09_03_00 20160520\SolverStudio\SolverStudio\SolverStudio.vsto'.
   em System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   em System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   em System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   em System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
   em System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
   em System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   em System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
   em System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

Followed [this help](https://solverstudio.org/help-comments/) tutorial

Comment: I have found this hotfix for this problem as NDP20SP2-KB981574-x64
However, it says that none of the programs for this hotfix is installed on the computer… I don’t know how to solve this problem

   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2012/10/08/troubleshooting-common-vsto-issues-part-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link helped to solve](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb53c217-4ac1-463f-9131-61ced9f090b7/downloading-file-desktopxxxvsto-did-not-succeed?forum=vsto)

I had to move the folder of installation to the DESKTOP!